# Alexa Skill: Allow an address (street + city) OR an airport for input?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using the Alexa Skills Kit and would like someone to be able to specify a location to be taken to.  This could either be a an address (123 Main St, Springfield, MA) or an airport (Atlanta Airport).

I see Alexa has default slot types of `AMAZON.Airports`, `AMAZON.PostalAddress` and `AMAZON.US_CITY`, but I cannot figure out how to accept either an airport or an address+city into a slot.

Example of what I'm trying to perform:

*Alexa, ask Jarvis to schedule a ride to 123 Main St, Springfield on Friday*

or

*Alexa, ask Jarvis to schedule a ride to JFK on Saturday*

I'm trying to make this as natural as possible, so requiring I change the language per target type (ex: "schedule a ride" means airport -vs- "book a ride" means address) is counter-productive.  I have tried that already, but as I said, it was counter-productive, and if I made the Intent names too similar ("book me a ride" -vs- "book me a ride to the airport") Alexa would get easily confused.

I am running PHP on my server, though if I can handle this in the skill JSON itself that would be ideal.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I've been using Stack for some time and seen this copy/paste before, but I don't see how it works using the Skills Kit (which is a sort of WYSIWYG editor) and fixed values (think proprietary enums).  That's the whole point of the question; I'm not trying to fix a bug but rather don't know how to START going about mixing/matching slot types aside from Googling for that, which I of course tried before going to Stack.

Comment: Are the locations parseable such that they can be used as a conditional to determine which slot type to search? Basically, can you require use of the word "Airport" when searching for airports? I don't feel like requiring a phrase such as "Alexa, ask Jarvis to schedule a ride to JFK _Airport_ on Saturday" would be "counterproductive". Alternatively, perhaps you could define an order of preference, and if no results are found in the first, it proceeds to the next.

Comment: I'd think forcing the word `airport` later in the script would be fine, but if the only way I can "branch" the two options is with two Intents I have a conflict of Intent name.  If I put both the address and the airport as non-required fields, then someone could submit without specifying EITHER.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use one intent with 2 different utterances:

FirstIntent schedule a ride to {AIRPORT_SLOT} airport
FirstIntent schedule a ride to {ADDRESS_SLOT}

Or you can use 2 separate in intents with the different utterances:

AirportIntent schedule a ride to {AIRPORT_SLOT} airport
AddressIntent schedule a ride to {ADDRESS_SLOT}

If you take the first approach, using a single intent, then your intent will need to check to see which slot, if any, is returned.

I would choose to use separate intents, and refactor the common code to function called by both intent handlers.